# i am getting this error message when i try to execute my web application

Tags: c#, error-handling, proxy

Error message is:

> Exception type: System.Net.WebException Message: The remote server
>   returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

I have these on the web.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>`n`
      <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Not sure if i need to include any other parameters

Comment: This is what i have on my web.config file 
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

Comment: Welcome to SO :) when you want to write code you can indent it with 4 spaces before each line or select it and press the code sample button. btw you have a \`n\` in your code sample

Comment: i just noticed that, i will make sure i do that on my next question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the proxy needs some credentials in order to grant access. You can try the default credentials..

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
```

If this doesn't work... you're going to have to add some code to create network credentials to pass to a proxy server.

Comment: i also had these:
<add key="ProxyUsername" value="username" />
<add key="ProxyPassword" value="password" />
<add key="ProxyDomain" value="mydomain" />